# Prolog Words Function

Tags: string, list, parsing, dictionary, prolog

I'm a beginner with Prolog and there's a piece of code I've been trying to implement.

Essentially, you enter a string where the words inside the string are separated by spaces or exclamation marks or commas etc.

The string is returned as a list of strings with the words parsed out.

So for example, "stack,overflow!rocks." will return ["stack","overflow","rocks"]

I'd like to use swi prolog assoc or some map structure to look up the boundary characters but I can't figure it out.

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Those double quoted strings are really *lists* of character codes. Then a DCG is the appropriate way to handle the parsing:

```
:- use_module(library(http/dcg_basics), [string//1]).

%% split input on Sep
splitter(Sep, [Chunk|R]) -->
    string(Chunk),
    (   Sep -> !, splitter(Sep, R)
    ;   [], {R = []}
    ).
```

`Sep` above can be a literal, or a non terminal. We need something like

```
not_in_word --> [C], {\+code_type(C, alpha)}.
```

with such definitions:

```
?- phrase(splitter(not_in_word, X), "stack,overflow!rocks.").
X = [[115, 116, 97, 99, 107], [111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111|...], [114, 111, 99, 107, 115], []] .
```

We can get rid of the empty strings using delete/3:

```
?- phrase(splitter(not_in_word, X), "? stack,overflow!rocks."), delete(X, [], Y).
X = [[], [], [115, 116, 97, 99, 107], [111, 118, 101, 114, 102|...], [114, 111, 99, 107|...], []],
Y = [[115, 116, 97, 99, 107], [111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111|...], [114, 111, 99, 107, 115]] .
```

**edit** We can visualize the words easily as atoms:

```
?- phrase(splitter(not_in_word, X), "? stack,overflow!rocks."),
   delete(X, [], Y),
   maplist(atom_codes, Z, Y).
X = [[], [], [115, 116, 97, 99, 107], [111, 118, 101, 114, 102|...], [114, 111, 99, 107|...], []],
Y = [[115, 116, 97, 99, 107], [111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111|...], [114, 111, 99, 107, 115]],
Z = [stack, overflow, rocks] .
```

Note the 'output' words positions in maplist(atom_codes, Atoms, Codes)...

Comment: Is there a way for me to see the actual words instead of character codes that are returned? Is this possible without having to convert the character codes?

Comment: You can use format('~s', [AnyOfY]), or see the edited answer.